# what prevents the race condition between kfifo_put and kfifo_is_empty for accessing __kfifo->in?

Tags: linux-kernel

In kfifo.h kfifo_get calls kfifo_is_empty which checks if __kfifo->in == __kfifo_out. Meanwhile kfifo_put does __kfifo->in++ after adding data. Since this is a lockless implementation of circular buffer with 1 reader and writer what prevents the writer from corrupting the data while kfifo_is_empty is reading the value of __kfifo->in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here.

In short, the reader may see `in` not equal to `out` **only after** data has been transferred into the kfifo. This is achived by executing *barrier* before incrementing `in` counter at the writer side.

Comment: so the read and write of in can be assumed to be atomic? It can never happen that kfifo_is_empty sees a value of in while only 2 of 4 bytes have been written by kfifo_put on all architectures. does the memory barrier guarantee this between 2 threads?

Comment: Yes, reading and writting into `in` can be assumed as *atomic*. This is true for native `int` type (and smaller ones). Barrier enforces that operations issued before it are visible for all other threads (cores) before the next instruction after the barrier is executed.